# Advantages to create Male and Female entities separate from User rather than making gender a property in a database?

Tags: database-theory, databases

The screenshot is from [Georgia Tech's CS-6400](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud150/lessons/5831689048/concepts/58325689630923). The instructor was talking about inheritance of Sub-Types and Super-Types.

[image]

My question is, why are `Male` and `Female` created as separate entities from the `User` entity here? Is it just for illustration purposes? Can we simply add a `gender` property to `User`, which values can be male or female?

Comment: (A matter of perspective. Is there notable difference in behaviour?)